# Reorder columns in wide dataframe of repeat in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, tidyr

150 repeat observations are in a reshaped dataframe *csvwide* including 1,351 columns with id_col "study_id" and variables:

```
    > variables
    # [1] "proanbx_dt"           "proanbx_tm"           "proanbx_name"        
    # [4] "proanbx_otherantibio" "proanbx_route"        "proanbx_dosage"      
    # [7] "proanbx_units"        "proanbx_doses"        "proanbx_freq"

    > unique(csfwide$study_id)
    # [1] "CHLA_0014" "CHLA_0042" "CHLA_0062" "CHLA_0065" "CHLA_0067" "CHLA_0079"
    # [7] "CHLA_0081" "CHLA_0083" "CHLA_0085" "CHLA_0086" "CHLA_0087" "CHLA_0089"
    # [13] "CHLA_0090" "CHLA_0091" "CHLA_0094" "CHLA_0095" "CHLA_0097" "CHLA_0099"
    # [19] "CHLA_0102" "CHLA_0103" "CHLA_0104" "CHLA_0105" "CHLA_0106" "CHLA_0107"
    # [25] "CHLA_0108" "CHLA_0109" "CHLA_0110"
```

The variables are currently ordered proanbx_dt1-150, proanbx_tm1-150, ..., proanbx_freq1-150:

```
    > head(csfwide)
    # A tibble: 6 × 1,351
    # study_id  proanbx_dt1 proanbx_dt2 proanbx_dt3 proanbx_dt4 proanbx_dt5
    # <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
    # 1 CHLA_0014 8/10/21     8/10/21     8/11/21     8/12/21     9/2/21     
    # 2 CHLA_0042 1/20/21     1/21/21     1/22/21     1/22/21     1/22/21    
    # 3 CHLA_0062 4/22/21     4/26/21     6/12/21     6/13/21     6/16/21    
    # 4 CHLA_0065 4/15/21     4/19/21     4/19/21     5/22/21     5/22/21    
    # 5 CHLA_0067 6/27/21     6/27/21     6/28/21     6/30/21     5/13/21    
    # 6 CHLA_0079 7/18/21     7/18/21     7/27/21     7/28/21     7/28/21    
    # … with 1,345 more variables: proanbx_dt6 <chr>, proanbx_dt7 <chr>,
    #   proanbx_dt8 <chr>, proanbx_dt9 <chr>, proanbx_dt10 <chr>,
    #   proanbx_dt11 <chr>, proanbx_dt12 <chr>, proanbx_dt13 <chr>,
    #   proanbx_dt14 <chr>, proanbx_dt15 <chr>, proanbx_dt16 <chr>,
    #   proanbx_dt17 <chr>, proanbx_dt18 <chr>, proanbx_dt19 <chr>,
    #   proanbx_dt20 <chr>, proanbx_dt21 <chr>, proanbx_dt22 <chr>,
    #   proanbx_dt23 <chr>, proanbx_dt24 <chr>, proanbx_dt25 <chr>, …
```

I want the columns grouped by observation as the value *variables* shown first above, in numeric order 1-150. To illustrate,

```
    > csfwide[ , c("study_id", "proanbx_dt1", "proanbx_tm1", "proanbx_name1", 
    "proanbx_otherantibio1", "proanbx_route1", "proanbx_dosage1", 
    "proanbx_units1","proanbx_doses1", "proanbx_freq1")]
    # A tibble: 27 × 10
    # study_id proanbx_dt1 proanbx_tm1 proanbx_name1 proanbx_otheran… proanbx_route1
    # <chr>    <chr>       <chr>       <chr>         <chr>            <chr>         
    # 1 CHLA_00… 8/10/21     9:41:00     90, Other     bacitracin topi… Topical       
    # 2 CHLA_00… 1/20/21     5:47:00     90, Other     mupirocin topic… Topical       
    # 3 CHLA_00… 4/22/21     14:16:00    90, Other     sulfamethoxazol… IV            
    # 4 CHLA_00… 4/15/21     16:51:00    90, Other     penicillin G po… IV            
    # 5 CHLA_00… 6/27/21     20:01:00    6, Ampicillin NA               IV            
    # 6 CHLA_00… 7/18/21     13:12:00    90, Other     nystatin topical Topical       
    # 7 CHLA_00… 7/7/21      10:09:00    90, Other     mupirocin topic… Topical       
    # 8 CHLA_00… 6/23/21     18:07:00    1, Cefazolin… NA               IV            
    # 9 CHLA_00… 7/27/21     12:19:00    90, Other     cephalexin       PO            
    # 10 CHLA_00… 2/27/21     8:26:00     90, Other     erythromycin     PO            
    # … with 17 more rows, and 4 more variables: proanbx_dosage1 <dbl>,
    #   proanbx_units1 <chr>, proanbx_doses1 <int>, proanbx_freq1 <int>
```

Please let me know if I can clarify or provider further information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `csfwide[,order(parse_number(names(csfwide)))]`

Comment: `csfwide[,c(1,order(parse_number(names(csfwide)[-1]))+1)]`